# Where does a Server trigger save in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

A couple of days ago , I was practicing and I wrote some triggers like these :

```
create trigger trg_preventionDrop
on all server 
for drop_database
as
print 'Can not Drop Database'
rollback tran

go 

create trigger trg_preventDeleteTable
on database
for drop_table
as 
print 'you can not delete any table'
rollback tran
```

But the problem is I don't know where it has saved and How can I delete or edit those.

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Server Trigger**

You can see them here

```
select * from sys.server_triggers
```

To drop use this syntax

```
drop trigger trg_preventionDrop on all server
```

In Management Studio they are under the "Server Objects" -> "Triggers" node

**Database Trigger**

You can see them here

```
select * from yourdb.sys.triggers
```

To drop use this syntax

```
drop trigger trg_preventDeleteTable on database
```

In Management Studio they are under the "Databases" -> "yourdb" -> "Programmability" -> "Database Triggers" node

Comment: The body of normal triggers are stored in sys.sql_modules. Where are the bodies of server triggers stored?

Comment: @zespri `sys.server_sql_modules`

Comment: @MartinSmith, yep, thanks, found it about ten seconds later after typing the question.

Answer (score 3):

trigger on a particular table resides in "DataBase" -> "YourDb" -> "YourTable" -> "Trigger" folder in Management Studio

also one can find the trigger on a particular table by execution the following sql:
EXEC sp_helptrigger yourtablename