# Can't see the triggers that I created in SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created a simple trigger on Albums table. But that trigger is not visible in object explorer in programmability in triggers folder. I refreshed that folder as well as restarted the SSMS but still no luck. However i can see that trigger under that table in triggers folder. Is this a feature or a bug?

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to find where triggers are stored in sql server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177594/unable-to-find-where-triggers-are-stored-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The triggers in Programmability is for database triggers ([DDL Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406.aspx)). You can view the table triggers ([DML Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191524.aspx)) if you expand the table. 
For example, you are looking for triggers for table "students" Follow: 
expand "Tables"=> Expand "students"=> Here you will find DML triggers in Triggers Node.

Comment: So simple... why didn't I just check there?

Answer (score 59):

Here is where the Triggers for a specific table is located:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you still can't find it, it is likely because you specified

```
CREATE TRIGGER X
ON SERVER ALL
```

Specifying that it is deployed at the server level.

Expand server objects > Triggers

Answer (score 1):

Collapse the tab of the Database and then refresh(F5) and expand TableName > Triggers> and here are your triggers(That need to be executed first before getting automatically saved.).