# SQL server 2008 r2 Trigger location

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

Where can i find the location of triggers that built on database, I had search on Google but i couldn't get any result.

My trigger script is :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [log]
ON DATABASE
FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS 
AS
DECLARE @data XML
SET @data = EVENTDATA()
....
....
```

Comment: What do you mean by *location of triggers* ?

Comment: If you mean, where can i find the tigger on the "Object Explorer" of the SSMS?

Comment: yes that what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this picture helpful............

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**To list them:**

```
SELECT 
     sysobjects.name AS trigger_name 
    ,USER_NAME(sysobjects.uid) AS trigger_owner 
    ,s.name AS table_schema 
    ,OBJECT_NAME(parent_obj) AS table_name 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsUpdateTrigger') AS isupdate 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsDeleteTrigger') AS isdelete 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsInsertTrigger') AS isinsert 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsAfterTrigger') AS isafter 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsInsteadOfTrigger') AS isinsteadof 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'ExecIsTriggerDisabled') AS [disabled] 
FROM sysobjects 

INNER JOIN sysusers 
    ON sysobjects.uid = sysusers.uid 

INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
    ON sysobjects.parent_obj = t.object_id 

INNER JOIN sys.schemas s 
    ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id 

WHERE sysobjects.type = 'TR'
```

SOURCE: [Need to list all triggers in SQL Server database with table name and table's schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305691/need-to-list-all-triggers-in-sql-server-database-with-table-name-and-tables-sch)

**To view them:**

[image]

SOURCE:[Can't see the triggers that i created in sql server management studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369599/cant-see-the-triggers-that-i-created-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008)

Comment: No, I know where i can find a trigger built on table, but i don't know the location ( on object explorer) of trigger that built on Database

Comment: Under the triggers folder as in the image above?

Comment: Do you mean in the right click menu and then location object option?

Comment: If you right click on the trigger (or a function for that matter) you can choose locate object

Comment: :) How can I Right click on the trigger if I cant find it in the object explorer !

Comment: The location is in the image above... Databases > System Databases > (YourDbName) > Tables > (YourTableName) > Triggers > (YourTriggerName)