# insert statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint? Why is this an issue in my case?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net, sql-server-2012

I know this gets asked a lot, but in my case, I feel like it shouldn't be an issue.
My table has 2 foreign keys that allow for nulls, so I should be able to leave them blank, right?

My insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO Child (ChildID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Gender, DOB)
VALUES (@ChildID, @FirstName, @MiddleName, @LastName, @Gender, @DOB)
```

I was hoping it would just leave the final 2 columns blank, for them to be filled out later, but all it does is give me an error.

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Child__ChildGuar__2B3F6F97". The conflict occurred in database "ChildCare", table "dbo.ChildGuardian", column 'ChildGuardianID'.
```

I can re-work the database a little, if necessary.

Comment: --> " The conflict occurred in database "ChildCare", table "dbo.ChildGuardian", column 'ChildGuardianID'" - Do you have a trigger firing perhaps?

Comment: I don't even know what a trigger is. How can I check for something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried passing in `NULL` for those values? You shouldn't have to pass anything, but it may help with troubleshooting.

I'd also check that `Child.ChildGuardianID` isn't an identity, and that it doesn't have a default value.

Comment: I gave it a default value before without thinking about that.
Thank you!

Comment: To check for triggers as @mitch wheat suggested, take a look here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177594/unable-to-find-where-triggers-are-stored-in-sql-server-2008) Note that you'll probably need SSMS to check/alter any of this stuff.

Comment: Oops, posted too late. Great! Don't forget to mark as answered :)

Comment: Is there an official way of doing that?